# Getting data from MS Access via php

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo, cyrillic

I have data stored in ms access database.

I have already connected to it with a simple code

```
$connStr = 
        'odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};' .
        'Dbq=C:\\Users\\kosm7\\Desktop\\1.mdb;' .
        'CharacterSet=UTF-8;';

$dbh = new PDO($connStr);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = 
        "SELECT * FROM Пол";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

// query parameter value(s)

$sth->execute();

while ($row = $sth->fetch()) {
    echo $row['1'] . "\r\n";
}
```

Basically, the problem is that table's name and values are named in Cyrillic, that's why ODBC is throwing a error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: -1305 [Microsoft][??????? ODBC Microsoft Access] ???? ???? Microsoft Access ?? ??????? ????? ??????? ??????? ??? ?????? "Пол". ?????????, ??? ?????? ??????????, ? ??? ??? ??????? ?????????. 
(SQLExecute[-1305] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:257) in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:36 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(36): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 36
```

Any thoughts on how to fix that?

Comment: Why not try the same code, with a simple MS access database, which doesn't contain  names in Cyrillic? That would be an easy test to see if your hypothesis that the characters are to blame is true. Alternatively you could try backticks around the names: `"SELECT * FROM \`Пол\`"`

Comment: If that would be that easy... =)

I just got a prepared database with forms connected to it and a lot of data and relationships made inside...

Backticks didn't work out ;(

Comment: Yeah, I thought that backticks wouldn't suffice. However, if you have the MS access program, making a simple database shouldn't be difficult. It makes perfect sense to first try and get the PHP-PDO-ODBC-MDB chain working before you try it on a complex database.

Comment: Thanks, will try to work this out =)

For now will try to switch to node js, found a pretty library ```node-adodb```, which might have a solution with an encoding issue